# how to set background color of title bar of popup window in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Can any one please tel me that how to set background color of title bar of popup window in jquery.

Title text is "Email Options".

```
 function showEmailDlg() {

    var dlg = $('#dlgEmail').dialog(
           {
               draggable: true,
               position: 'center',
               modal: true,
               width: 1028,
               height: 568,
               title: 'Email Options',
               resizable: false

           }
       );

    dlg.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
}
```

Comment: What dialog plug-in are you using, jQuery UI?

Comment: open mozilla , debug mode , select the title bar , check where its css is coming from , modify the plug in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery UI (it looks like you are), as far as I'm aware there's no documented option for it, but jQuery UI uses CSS for styling and makes sure the classes are *fairly* clear.

In this case, the dialog title element (a `div`) has the class `ui-dialog-titlebar`. You can apply styling using a selector matching that (e.g., `#dlgEmail .ui-dialog-titlebar`). If you just want the bit containing the title and not the full title bar, that's a `span` with class `.ui-dialog-title`. But note that there's a lot of intricate styling done in the jQuery UI stuff, it's going to be a bit non-trivial.

Using any half-decent browser, you can discover this stuff at runtime. For instance, with Chrome, just left-click the title bar and choose "Inspect element".

Comment: I am using Visual studio. please tell me in that context.

Comment: @riaz100: It doesn't matter what dev tool you're using, you just style that content -- just like styling any other content, with a stylesheet.

Comment: Done! I changed in the file "jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css"

Comment: @riaz100: Cool, glad that helped. Another way would be to override the style in a stylesheet loaded after (or with a more specific rule), but that works too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
$("#dlgEmail .ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: Done! I changed in the file "jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" downloaded from  http://jquery.org/. in .ui-dialog-titlebar class i changed     background-color: red;

Comment: If you edit that file it will appear in everywhere you use the popup, but you may want to keep the default color in other popups right. because of that use this way to only change this popup title bar. put this just after you initialize the popup script.